# set state of variable inside an inner component

Tags: reactjs, state

I have a simple react component which holds states. The component is getting really long and I want to separate it to smaller components.

```
export default function FatherComponent(props) {
const [name, setName] = useState('');

... other functionality ...

return (
<div className="main-container">
  {renderBody()}
  <SonComponent
    name={name}/>
</div>
```

and then I removed some of the code that deals with `name` into the son's component, and some is still handled in the father's component (that's why I don't completely move it inside).

Inside the son's component, how can I change the value of `name`, make it that the value of `name` is changing as well in the father's component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass `setName` to the son component.
But good practise is to create a handler.

For example:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');

const setNameHandler = (name) => {
 setName(name);
}

/*...*/
<SonComponent
    name={name}
    setNameHandler={setNameHandler}
/>
/*...*/
```